# Storing a Bitmap into a ContentProvider from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, database, image

I'm working on an app that, upon instillation of certain apps will send a message to them to register with a content provider. It all works fine, the strings are stored, but I can't get the byte[] blob (a bitmap .png file) to convert properly from within `onReceive()` in the broadcastreceiver.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "onReceive, from within RegisterApp");
    this.context = context;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("app_name", getAppName());
    values.put("app_description", getAppDescription());

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap b = getAppIcon();
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    byte[] blob = stream.toByteArray();

    values.put("icon", blob);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(
            Uri.parse("content://blahblahblahblah"), values);
}
```

I hijack the context so that I can get a hold on the image from the getAppIcon() call (You extend this class which is an abstract class extending BroadcastReceiver)

i.e.

```
@Override
protected Bitmap getAppIcon() {
    Log.v(TAG, "putting icon");
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
}
```

But my understanding of the context is limited and I think this is what is causing it to be stored incorrectly.

I've also tried getting the bitmap from the resources when `onReceive()` is called and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm simply an idiot. Nothing is wrong with storing the image in this fashion (provided it is a .png), I simply forgot to setContentView().

Sorry!